# Alamofire Serial Requests

Tags: ios, alamofire

I need the requests to be executed in order, although this is not working using Alamofire.

I want to print 1 to 30 in sequence (assuming the response is just an echo for the parameter)

```
// Only 1 connection per Host

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost =  1
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
self.manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration) 

for i in 1...30 {
    manager.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", "i" : i], encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch (response.result){
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("error")
                break;
            case .Success(let json):
                print(json)
            }
     })
```

Comment: You stated your expectation but not your result. If you didn't see 1...30 what did you see and what do you think that means is wrong?

Comment: @Jonah, I see the the numbers 1 to 30, but not ordered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per `NSURLSessionConfiguration`'s documentation:

> This property determines the maximum number of simultaneous connections made to each host by tasks within sessions based on this configuration.
>
> This limit is per session, so if you use multiple sessions, your app as a whole may exceed this limit. Additionally, depending on your connection to the Internet, a session may use a lower limit than the one you specify.
>
> The default value is 6 in OS X, or 4 in iOS.

As you can see, this setting merely controls the number of connections on a network level. Once you queue up a number of requests using `NSURLSession`, which underlies Alamofire, it's up to that class to determine when your requests are made. There is no way, using `NSURLSession` or Alamofire, to guarantee the order in which requests are made without explicit coding them that way.

That said, by wrapping the requests in `NSOperation`s you may be able to get the behavior you want. If you create an `NSOperationQueue` with a `.maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `1`, you essentially create a serial queue. Then using the same loop you already wrote, you should be able to wrap your Alamofire requests like this:

```
queue.addOperationWithBlock {
    manager.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", "i" : i], encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch (response.result){
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("error")
                break;
            case .Success(let json):
                print(json)
            }
     })
}
```

With a `.maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `1`, the queue should act serially, as I mentioned. Therefore, your operations will execute in the order they were added to the queue, as per `NSOperationQueue`'s documentation. So you should see the the 1 to 30 result you want.

All of this said, there is likely a better solution to the problem you want to solve, unless this is merely a coding exercise to get these results in order.

Comment: Thanks!, yep I puzzled why the request are not executed in order.

Comment: this is not right manager.request is asynchronous and returned immediately, wrapping it like that does literally nothing

Comment: As long as you set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [Alamofire's Github page](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

> Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously. Asynchronous programming may be a source of frustration to programmers unfamiliar with the concept, but there are [very good reasons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html) for doing it this way.

So, by nature of using Alamofire, you are going to get async network calls. You could choose a different library or use the base SDK implementations, but as detailed in the Apple documentation link from Alamofire's Github page, there's a reason you're going to find almost every networking library is asynchronous.

So, to put it into context for you, the interface for Alamofire is receiving your calls synchronously, but past that, there's no guarantee what order the responses will get back to you in. They may make their request in a different order and they almost certainly will return responses in a different order.

A better option here would be to store a mutable array of responses and once it has a response stored from each network call you made, sort the array and then do your print.

Comment: Yeah, I know that Alamofire is Async and all the benefits of async programming. All the others request from the App are in this way. In fact, I already  found out an workaround for my problem. The real question Here is : "Why the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost =  1`" is not working as expected? Or what is the true meaning of the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` property?  Sorry if the question is not very  clear

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire 5:

```swift
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var session: Session?
    var opQueue: OperationQueue?
    var semaphore: DispatchSemaphore?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        synchronous()
    }

    
    func synchronous() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
        
        self.session = Session(configuration: configuration)
        self.opQueue = OperationQueue()
        self.opQueue?.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        self.semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        for i in 1...30 {
            self.opQueue?.addOperation { [weak self] in
                self?.session?.request("https://httpbin.org/get", method: .get, parameters: ["i" : i]).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response  in
                        switch (response.result){
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("error: \(error)")
                            break;
                        case .success(let json):
                            if let json = json as? Dictionary<String, Any>, let data = json["args"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                                print(data)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    self?.semaphore?.signal()
                 })
                
                self?.semaphore?.wait()
            }
            
        }
    }

}
```

log:

```
["i": 1]
["i": 2]
["i": 3]
["i": 4]
["i": 5]
["i": 6]
["i": 7]
["i": 8]
["i": 9]
["i": 10]
["i": 11]
["i": 12]
["i": 13]
["i": 14]
["i": 15]
["i": 16]
["i": 17]
["i": 18]
["i": 19]
["i": 20]
["i": 21]
["i": 22]
["i": 23]
["i": 24]
["i": 25]
["i": 26]
["i": 27]
["i": 28]
["i": 29]
["i": 30]
```